I try to model my mod file I get an error:Time is not defined context: param VTI {t in >>> Time, <<< l in Levels, k in FoodGroup} >= 0;

 param VTI {t in Time, l in Levels, k in Food Group} >= 0; param FC {t in Time} >= 0; param VS t {t in Time, k in Food Group, b in All Food Bank} >= 0; param VH t {t in Time, k in Food Group, b in All Food Bank} >= 0; param O {t in Time} >= 0; param Q tilde {t in Time, d in Financial Donors} >= 0;  param tau {t in Time, p in All Product} >= 0; param phi {t in Time, k in Food Group} >= 0;  param omega >= 0; param distance{i in I, j in J} >= 0; set Time := 1 2 3 4 5; param VTI :=  [1,1,1] 2.00, [1,2,1] 7.50, [1,3,1] 10.00, [2,1,1] 1.50, [2,2,1] 5.00, [2,3,1] 6.00, [3,1,1] 1.00, [3,2,1] 3.50, [3,3,1] 4.00; giap.mod, line 25 (offset 2096):Time is not defined context:  param VTI {t in  >>> Time, <<<  l in Levels, k in FoodGroup} >= 0;


That's valid AMPL syntax. The Time set is not defined in that context, maybe because you have not declared it, you reset; the problem, or maybe the declaration was wrong.
Could you share your model? How do you declare Time?

data;
Define sets and their cardinalities
#set Time := 1 2 3 4 5;           # |T| = 5

That's to give values to Time, but not a declaration. You still need to declare the set inside the model, stg like set Time;. You could also use directly set Time := 1..5; (inside the model, not inside a data section!)
